# How you can exclude compile file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have used dropbox and box with my application.
But when i have used Dropbox with latest SDK then some classes conflict with Box SDK.

So i have found one solution by which you can exclude group and compile file.

```
 compile('com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:2.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'//for Box
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'// this for PayPal

    }
```

Note:
By this all working well means 100%.

Comment: Is that a question? I can't see any problem here ....

Comment: It's suggestion :)

Comment: This would be something for the Documentation part of SO, definitely not for the question part